# Persisting entity fetched from Jackson Json in Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

Below is my scenario.

I have two entities.

1) Client

2) Project

Relationship among them is One client provides Many Projects. I have created both the entities in Hibernate as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="client")
public class Client extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long clientId;
   ......
   ......
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Project")
public class Project extends BaseEntity<Long>{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long projectId;
    .......

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientId")
    private Client client;

    .......

}
```

My Service Layer looks like,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody Project project, BindingResult result) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ........
        projectService.saveProject(project);

        ....

    }

}
```

My JSON while requesting the server is,

```
{
  "name": "Project 1",
  "description": "client Project 1",
  "startDate": "2012-07-21 12:11:12",
  "endDate": "2017-07-21 12:11:12",
  "totalPlannedReleases": 20,
  "projectKey": "MAQ",
  "avatar":"Not Available",
  "client": {"clientId":1}
}
```

My client (Parent entity) is already persisted in database. I have to reference the existing clientId to the new Project which I am inserting.

I am using Jackson as Json library

Is there any way so that Client entity can be mapped/fetched automatically while inserting Project?

Answer (score 0):

What does 'automatically' mean?

If `Project` is the owning side of the client - project relationship (which it probably should be as per your requirement), you can call `project.setClient(entityManager.getReference(Client.class, id))` (or `project.setClient(session.load(Client.class, id))` if you are using Hibernate session) to avoid loading the entire state of the `Client` entity from the database.